Does thermal energy increase with kinetic energy?
This is more of a clarifying question. Say we're using the model of a skate park because that's easier to picture. If a skater gains more potential energy (either from being atop of higher slope or having more mass), they will naturally gain more kinetic energy as they descend a slope. However, I was wondering if an object with more kinetic energy would also experience a faster increase in thermal energy (due to friction). This is excluding other minor forces and simply focusing on the concept. Thanks for the help.

First of all, friction is a non-conservative force, so it will basically be the  potential energy removed from the system, rather than letting it  convert to kinetic.
Friction depends on two things, the normal force and the coefficient of friction of the surfaces on contact (skater and the ground of the slope) neither of which depends on the velocity with which you're moving:
$$F_\text{friction} = \mu  F_\text{contact}.$$
So, higher kinetic energy wouldn't lead to a higher increase in thermal energy.
However, if you're talking about net increase, then as we go down a longer slope, more time will be taken to reach the bottom (assuming the skater doesn't stop in the middle of the path in any of these cases) and so more of the potential energy will convert to thermal energy as we stay in an area with friction. So while there wouldn't be any relation between the velocity with which it's moving and increase in thermal energy, the KE and so the velocity will be less at the bottom of the longer path than the shorter one.

As the skater descends, gravitational potential energy is converted to both thermal energy by friction and kinetic energy. So you would get an increase in both simultaneously. The friction is proportional to the normal force which is dependent on the skater's weight and the slope of the ramp. Mathematically, the increase in kinetic energy is change in potential energy minus heat due to friction.
Assuming constant slope of the ramp, energy lost to friction should be a constant proportion of the potential energy. So 20% of the change in potential energy might go into friction with 80% going to kinetic as a contrived example. This implies the kinetic energy would always be 4 times the thermal energy even though they are due to different mechanisms. The relevant forces don't change with initial speed along the ramp. This in turn means the ratio of potential energy shared between friction and kinetic energy remains unchanged. This changes if ignore wind resistance which is indeed proportional to some power of the velocity.
